# Cannot update Access Database DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to somehow **update** or **retrieve** again data from Access database ([Random piece of data with column names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8O6Cd.png))

I'm using `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`.

I created a query which should return records where a Column has a value between two dates:

**SQL** example:

```
SELECT Arkusz1.ID, Arkusz1.Adres, Arkusz1.Umówione, Arkusz1.Data_umówienia, Arkusz1.Zakończone, Arkusz1.[Spisano?], Arkusz1.Notatki  
FROM Arkusz1 
WHERE( 
     ((Arkusz1.Umówione) = Yes) // or 1 or <> 0
 AND ((Arkusz1.Zakończone) = No)  // or 0 doesen't provide right answer
 AND ((Arkusz1.Data_umówienia) BETWEEN 24/07/2021 AND 26/07/2021) ) 
 ORDER BY Arkusz1.Data_umówienia;
```

My code:

```
void fillGrid()
{
    string teraz = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString().Replace('.', '/');
    string jutro = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString().Replace('.', '/');
    // AddDays +-1 because of my data issue, that's not important

    string dzisiejsze = "SELECT Arkusz1.ID, Arkusz1.Adres, Arkusz1.Umówione, Arkusz1.Data_umówienia," 
        + " Arkusz1.Zakończone, Arkusz1.[Spisano?], Arkusz1.Notatki  FROM Arkusz1" 
        + " WHERE( ((Arkusz1.Umówione) = Yes) AND ((Arkusz1.Zakończone) = No) AND " 
        + "((Arkusz1.Data_umówienia) BETWEEN "
        + teraz + " AND " + jutro + ") )" 
        + " ORDER BY Arkusz1.Data_umówienia;";
        //selecting almost every column from my only sheet (Arkusz1), 
        //if Umówione (appointment is arranged) has True value AND issue is not ended (Zakończone) 
        //AND appointment date is between yesterday and tomorrow 
        //(as I said, that's all because my stupid ideas in creating DB)

    connection.Open();

    OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(dzisiejsze, connection);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
    TodaysPlan_dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
    TodaysPlan_dataGridView.Refresh();

    connection.Close();
}
```

I even added a special button to update the whole grid (firstly it was supposed to update after a second Form is closed):

```
private void refreshGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.DoEvents(); // because I saw something on stack, didn't work
    fillGrid(); //start filling again, didn't work too
    TodaysPlan_dataGridView.Refresh(); // same, didn't work
}
```

I don't get any error, execution (even in debug-mode) just passes by the code in `refreshGrid_Click`.

[Edit: Tried to execute that SQL code for random data, didn't work too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qm9jz.png)
Ofc that's not the most important part of my question but I could ask that in addition :)

I'll also provide code for *saving button from second form*, but in my opinion it won't be really helpful:

```
private void save_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((Tick_label.Visible == true) && (IDInfo_label.Text == "All good!") && (street_textBox.TextLength > 0))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string cmd_string = "INSERT INTO Arkusz1 (ID, Adres, Przydzielenie) VALUES ('" + ID_maskedTextBox.Text + "', '" + street_textBox.Text + "','" + startDate_dateTimePicker.Value + "')";
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(cmd_string, connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();

        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error");
    }
}
```

That's my first question on Stack, any suggestions and constructive criticism are welcome!

BTW, I was using [this YT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5EpbmcGmAY) tutorial, hope it helps someone :)

Comment: Two points:  First, you have not told us what kind of error do you get. Second, don't concatenate string to build sql queries. Use parameters

Comment: Third: Yes/No are not valid values for boolean fields. Use = 0 or <> 0

Comment: Right, give me a moment to edit question

Comment: @Steve
**One:** I don't have any error, even while debugging refreshGrid_Click() it just passes by, like execution already happened (but ofc nothing changed) **Two:** I used to concatenate strings because my main language is Python and It looked pretty good for me, but as You said - that's not the most elegant way :/ **Three:** Yes/No works in Access, C# query doesen't provide right answer, but doesn't return error, so I guess both ways are ok for SQL

Comment: A Boolean Field in Access accept a Parameter of Type `OleDbType.Boolean`, so your Parameter is set to a `bool` (`true/false`). A Date Field accepts `BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2`. The Parameters Type is `OleDbType.Date` -- If you don't use Parameters to pass your values, you have a giant problem. If your Date Fields are actually strings, you have a giant problem. If that's the case, solve these problems first. When you add Command Parameters with the correct data Type, the perspective changes. A lot.

Comment: It also appears that you're storing a Connection object to a Field. That's a bad mistake, especially with an Access db: create the Connection object in-place and dispose of it right after, along with the Command and DataReader (if any). Possiibly declaring your objects with `using` statements. You may want to use a DataAdapter to automate INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE commands. See the [OleDbDataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter) functionality. Call the `AcceptChanges()` method of a DataTable right after you have filled it.

Comment: _Yes/No works in Access_ that's a usual mistake. The Access UI is not the Access Jet Engine. When you _work with Access_ you are working with the Access UI that does a lot of things behind your shoulders. Like translating Yes/No to true/false. When you work with C# code you are talking directly to the Access Jet Engine and you need to take care yourself of these 'shortcuts'. For example dates (if concatenated to a string) should be passed in 'MM/dd/yyyy' format and enclosed in # (#07/26/2021#). This is one of the many reasons to use Parameters, not code elegancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, informations provided by @Steve and @Jimi were really helpful, firstly I changed string formatting using `String.Format()` and resolved SQL problem - which was *(#date#)* formatting:

```
DateTime tmp_teraz = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
string teraz = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", tmp_teraz.Month.ToString(), 
tmp_teraz.Day.ToString(), tmp_teraz.Year.ToString());

DateTime tmp_jutro = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
string jutro = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", tmp_jutro.Month.ToString(), tmp_jutro.Day.ToString(), tmp_jutro.Year.ToString());

string dzisiejsze = String.Format("SELECT Arkusz1.ID, Arkusz1.Adres, Arkusz1.Umówione, Arkusz1.Data_umówienia, Arkusz1.Zakończone, Arkusz1.[Spisano?], Arkusz1.Notatki  FROM Arkusz1 WHERE( ((Arkusz1.Umówione) = true) AND ((Arkusz1.Zakończone) = false) AND ((Arkusz1.Data_umówienia) " +
            "BETWEEN (#{0}#) AND (#{1}#)) ) ORDER BY Arkusz1.Data_umówienia;", teraz, jutro);
```

At the end, grid looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XKhN.png).

Refreshing or inserting data with dataGrid doesen't work, but that's a thing I'll develop over time.

Thanks for help and have a nice day guys!